# How to prevent the caller's shell from being used in sudo

Tags: bash, sudo, environment-variables

I'm running sudo-1.8.6 on CentOS 6.5. My question is very simple: How do I prevent SHELL from propagating from a user's environment to a sudo environment?

Usually people are going the other way- they want to preserve an environment variable. However, I am having an issue where my user "zabbix" whose shell is `/sbin/nologin` tries to run a command via sudo. Sudo is preserving the `/sbin/nologin` so that root cannot run subshells. *(Update: This part is true, but it is not the SHELL environment variable. It is the shell value that is being pulled from /etc/passwd that is the problem.)*

I include a test that illustrates the problem; this is not my real-world use case but it simply illustrates that the calling user's SHELL is preserved. I have a program that runs as user `zabbix`. It calls `/usr/bin/sudo -u root /tmp/doit` (the programming running as `zabbix` is a daemon, so the `/sbin/nologin` shell in the password file does not prevent it). `/tmp/doit` is a shell script that simply has:

```
#!/bin/sh
env > /tmp/outfile
```

(its mode is 755, obviously). In `outfile` I can see that `SHELL` is `/sbin/nologin`. However, at this point the script is running as root, via sudo, so it should not have the previous user's environment variables, right?

Here is my /etc/sudoers:

```
Defaults    requiretty
Defaults   !visiblepw

Defaults    always_set_home
Defaults    env_reset
Defaults    env_keep =  "COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS"
Defaults    env_keep += "MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE"
Defaults    env_keep += "LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY"
Defaults    secure_path = /sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin

## Allow root to run any commands anywhere 
root    ALL=(ALL)       ALL

#includedir /etc/sudoers.d
```

And here is my `/etc/sudoers.d/zabbix`:

```
Defaults:zabbix !requiretty

zabbix    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:       /tmp/doit
```

Edit: A little more information:

The process running the sudo is `zabbix_agentd`, from the Zabbix monitoring software. There is an entry in the `/etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.d/userparameter_disk.conf` file which looks like:

```
UserParameter=example.disk.discovery,/usr/local/bin/zabbix_raid_discovery
```

`/usr/local/bin/zabbix_raid_discovery` is a Python script. I have modified it to simply do this:

```
print subprocess.check_output(['/usr/bin/sudo', '-u', 'root', '/tmp/doit'])
```

`/tmp/doit` simply does this:

```
#!/bin/sh
env >> /tmp/outfile
```

I run the following on my Zabbix server to run the `/usr/local/bin/zabbix_raid_discovery` script:

```
zabbix_get -s client_hostname -k 'example.disk.discovery'
```

Then I check the `/tmp/outfile`, and I see:

```
SHELL=/sbin/nologin
TERM=linux
USER=root
SUDO_USER=zabbix
SUDO_UID=497
USERNAME=root
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/sbin
MAIL=/var/mail/root
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
SHLVL=1
SUDO_COMMAND=/tmp/doit
HOME=/root
LOGNAME=root
SUDO_GID=497
_=/bin/env
```

That `SHELL` line really bugs me. The file is owned by root, so I know it's being created by the root user, but the shell is from the calling user (`zabbix`).

Comment: @BinaryZebra - Yes I know about `env_delete`, but I agree the crux of the problem is that the default behavior of env_reset `...causes commands to be executed with a new, minimal environment.` We have a linux system with PAM, so according to the man page, `The new environment contains the ... SHELL ... (variable)`. As you can see from my `/etc/sudoers` file above, we do not allow `SHELL` in the `env_keep`. So `SHELL` should not be preserved; we should have the root user's `SHELL`.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - I have added `zabbix    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:       /bin/env SHELL=/bin/sh /tmp/doit *` to my `/etc/sudoers/zabbix` file, and it has a proper shell. Thanks, I now have a workaround. The question is, why did I need to include it? It seems dangerous (and broken) to pass the caller's SHELL but I can find no place where sudo is set to modify it. I have run `find /etc/sudoers /etc/sysconfig -type f -exec grep env_ {} \;` and I find no red flags; `/etc/sudoers` contains the only `env_` string. So I don't think there is a sudoers flag interfering...

Comment: Mike: On a first level: A simple `sudo bash` should start a bash shell as root and it MUST have the SHELL variable set to the value from /etc/password. You report that SHELL is being set to (or preserved as) `/sbin/nologin`. That is a security issue, the shell started by root must not be controlled by an environment variable set by an user. That is something you must investigate.

Comment: Mike: Second, if this: `zabbix ALL=(root) NOPASSWD: /bin/env SHELL=/bin/sh /tmp/doit *` works for you, I would not waste more time on this. This is a safe way to set the environment variables.

Comment: Mike: third: Yes I am as lost as you as who is changing/setting/controling the SHELL variable. I strongly suspect it is PAM, but can not confirm (or negate) yet.

Comment: @adonis - See my second answer. The fact is, sudo up to the latest version (and starting when?) contains a bug as of this writing. The bug bit me because my script did not work as expected- it broke because it was using the caller's shell of `/sbin/nologin`, and it should not have. It's that simple.

Comment: @adonis Answering « Unfortunately, I still fail to understand why this poses a problem in your use case.» I suspect that the problem of Mike is that the shell variable defines the started shell for the ROOT user, as I understand his reports.

Comment: @BinaryZebra - Exactly. A user with a shell of /sbin/nologin was running a daemon, which called a program (no problem so far- it's not a shell)- which then tried to run a system command using sudo as root, which THEN tried to exec a system program using the shell. The shell it was given to use was /sbin/nologin. This is the caller's shell, NOT root's shell, which it should have used. Thanks to you and adonis for the conversation and help; for now I will use the workaround which works fine.

Comment: @adonis The SHELL variable must be set to the value from /etc/password even in the "minimal environment" you mention.

Comment: @adonis - Your man page must be old, and not so explicit. Regardless, your understanding is backwards. First, the fact that `env_reset` is enabled, means that environment variables should NOT come from the caller's environment. The fact that all the other variables such as HOME are of the callee further underscores this fact. The maintainer of the software asserts that the current behavior is a bug, and has a fix. As to your response to BinaryZebra: You are correct- SHELL comes from /etc/passwd of the calling user. This is wrong, and as the maintainer says, not in alignment with the manual.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Then answer is that `sudo` has a bug. First, the workaround: I put this in my `/etc/sudoers.d/zabbix file`:

```
zabbix    ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:       /bin/env SHELL=/bin/sh /usr/local/bin/zabbix_raid_discovery
```

and now subcommands called from `zabbix_raid_discovery` work.

A patch to fix this will be in sudo 1.8.15. From the maintainer, Todd Miller:

```
This is just a case of "it's always been like that".  There's not
really a good reason for it.  The diff below should make the behavior
match the documentation.

 - todd

diff -r adb927ad5e86 plugins/sudoers/env.c
--- a/plugins/sudoers/env.c     Tue Oct 06 09:33:27 2015 -0600
+++ b/plugins/sudoers/env.c     Tue Oct 06 10:04:03 2015 -0600
@@ -939,8 +939,6 @@
            CHECK_SETENV2("USERNAME", runas_pw->pw_name,
                ISSET(didvar, DID_USERNAME), true);
        } else {
-           if (!ISSET(didvar, DID_SHELL))
-               CHECK_SETENV2("SHELL", sudo_user.pw->pw_shell, false, true);
            /* We will set LOGNAME later in the def_set_logname case. */
            if (!def_set_logname) {
                if (!ISSET(didvar, DID_LOGNAME))
@@ -984,6 +982,8 @@
            if (!env_should_delete(*ep)) {
                if (strncmp(*ep, "SUDO_PS1=", 9) == 0)
                    ps1 = *ep + 5;
+               else if (strncmp(*ep, "SHELL=", 6) == 0)
+                   SET(didvar, DID_SHELL);
                else if (strncmp(*ep, "PATH=", 5) == 0)
                    SET(didvar, DID_PATH);
                else if (strncmp(*ep, "TERM=", 5) == 0)
@@ -1039,7 +1039,9 @@
     if (reset_home)
        CHECK_SETENV2("HOME", runas_pw->pw_dir, true, true);

-    /* Provide default values for $TERM and $PATH if they are not set. */
+    /* Provide default values for $SHELL, $TERM and $PATH if not set. */
+    if (!ISSET(didvar, DID_SHELL))
+       CHECK_SETENV2("SHELL", runas_pw->pw_shell, false, false);
     if (!ISSET(didvar, DID_TERM))
        CHECK_PUTENV("TERM=unknown", false, false);
     if (!ISSET(didvar, DID_PATH))
```

Comment: Excellent Mike !, Thanks for the detective work.

Comment: Mike, is it possible that you put a link to the (future?) patch.

Comment: @BinaryZebra Diff is here: http://www.sudo.ws/repos/sudo/rev/b77adbc08c91 I don't see a patch as yet.

Comment: Mike: I believe that you are barking to the wrong tree. The key point here: `Provide default values for $SHELL, $TERM and $PATH if not set.` is: `... if not set.`. Any value set will be preserved by sudo. Who is setting SHELL?

Comment: @BinaryZebra - That's not how I read it. SHELL is unset (by env_reset, by default). Since it's unset, the old code says to use sudo_user's pw entry. The new code says to use the runas user's pw entry.

Answer (score 4):

The question was about where I thought the problem was, but it turns out that the issue is not what happens to the SHELL variable, but what sudo actually does. For example:

```
-bash-4.1$ whoami
testdude
-bash-4.1$ grep testdude /etc/passwd
testdude:x:1001:10:Test dude:/tmp:/bin/bash
-bash-4.1$ sudo env
[sudo] password for testdude: 
...
SHELL=/bin/bash
...
```

So far so good. ...but the problem is that sudo uses the shell of the caller instead of the callee, contrary to the docs. Indeed, if I change my shell by editing /etc/passwd, you can see that sudo follows the shell of the caller and not `SHELL`:

```
-bash-4.1$ grep root /etc/passwd
root:x:0:0:root:/root:/bin/bash
-bash-4.1$ sudo sed -i -e '/testdude/s/bash/sh/' /etc/passwd
-bash-4.1$ grep testdude /etc/passwd
testdude:x:1001:10:Test dude:/tmp:/bin/sh
-bash-4.1$ sudo env
...
SHELL=/bin/sh
...
-bash-4.1$ export SHELL=/completely/meaningless/path
-bash-4.1$ sudo env
...
SHELL=/bin/sh
...
```

I can't use `sudo -i` because I don't want to simulate an initial login. `sudo -s` will work, as long as I have the proper command in the sudoers file. However, the expected behavior (as reflected in the man page: "`The new environment contains the TERM, PATH, HOME, MAIL, SHELL, LOGNAME, USER, USERNAME and SUDO_* variables`") is for the shell to be the callee's. If you look at the `PATH`, `HOME`, `LOGNAME`, and `USER` variables for sudo env you will see root's stuff. `SHELL` should be root's shell as well.